The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data
I'm using MySQL Database and using MS Access as a frontend for reporting and gathering data by linking to the MySQL existing tables
When I import the data from the tables, I can display the data without any problem. When I link to the tables using an ODBC connection and try to view the table, I get the following error:

The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data.
Microsoft Access can't open the table in Datasheet view."

I was expecting to be able to work with the data as is.
I am not inserting or pasting any data. I have checked the data types and they match, no field is larger that 255 Characters
I have tried different Data base connection settings, like:

Return matched rows instead of affected rows
Return SQL_NULL_DATA for zero date

I've tried different ODBC Connectors from 8.4.0 to 5.3.0 with no luck.
I've tried different settings in MS Access like

Support Large Number (Bigint) Data Type for linked/Imported Tables
Support Date Time Extended (DateTime2) Data Type for linked/Imported Tables


If you open the linked table directly (not the datasheet view of form), does it work?

You can avoid  this problem by using Pass-Through query, That's go directly to the SQL Server and bypass ms-access engine.

If i double click on the table I get the same error.

What data type is used for date/time fields?

@xShen, a SELECT PT query does not allow editing data.

No it's not, it's refer to what you write "using an ODBC connection and try to view the table" ‏not editing just view. ‏if you need to update then you have to do something like update query.

second thought about your problem . I never experienced it  myself so maybe this is something wrong with your table, the easiest way to understand it ,Is to make a brand new table with 2 columns in the SQL server just to check if it the same behavior, If not then do a simple select query on the problematic table and run it each and every time remove one field until you catch the one that create  the problem.

Data type for Date is Date from MySQL table linked. MS Access shows Date/Time for the same column of the linked table.

Pass-Through queries Comment from xShen solved my issue. sorry for the late response.
